# Units hidden from systemctl 20.04

Tags: systemd

During some troubleshooting of journal errors, I have run into a situation with systemctl and the unit tracker-miner-fs. I have tried several forms of the command and cannot get systemctl to find the unit.

`systemctl status` does show the service listed and system status is running (no failed units)

`systemctl status tracker-miner-fs` : Not Found
`systemctl list-units tracker-miner-fs` : Not Found
`systemctl list-unit-files tracker-miner-fs` : Not Found
`systemctl list-unit-files tracker-miner-fs -all` : Not Found
`systemctl -all` : Not listed
`systemctl stop tracker-miner-fs` : Not found
`systemctl unmask tracker-miner-fs` :Not found

All forms have been tried with sudo and without. It's not that this particular unit is causing trouble, but it does beg the question why? And is there some peculiar setting that may be hiding other units and causing unknown errors?

Can any one shed some light on this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tracker miner is set up as a user unit, not a system unit (all it does is index some folders in a user's home directory). In order to find it, you need to explicitly tell `systemd` to look in the user units (To be more precise, you're telling `systemd` which service manager it should use).

You can retry all the above commands by including the `--user` option and should be able to manage the service. Note that `sudo` will not be required with `systemctl --user` commands.

For example in my case:

*Note I'm on Ubuntu 21.10 which ships with Tracker 3, so the service name is different*

```
$ systemctl --user restart tracker-miner-fs-3.service
$ systemctl status tracker-miner-fs-3.service 
Unit tracker-miner-fs-3.service could not be found.
$ systemctl --user status tracker-miner-fs-3.service 
● tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/tracker-miner-fs-3.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-02-04 12:50:14 CET; 5min ago
   Main PID: 13141 (tracker-miner-f)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 14089)
     Memory: 8.2M
        CPU: 183ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/background.slice/tracker-miner-fs-3.service
             └─13141 /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3

Feb 04 12:50:14 danny systemd[1624]: Starting Tracker file system data miner...
Feb 04 12:50:14 danny systemd[1624]: Started Tracker file system data miner.
```

You can also find this out from the `systemctl status` command as the unit will be listed under `user.slice` instead of `system.slice`.

Comment: Thank you, I figured I was missing something obvious.